# How to Differentiate input vs button state changes in react redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-redux-form

I've got a simple login dialog that uses redux (just the dialog is shown below for reference). Each time the user types a character into either of the input fields a state change is fired through redux and when the button is pressed a state change also fires.

I plan on changing the state directly when the button is pressed to be something like "LoginPending", and when the REST call returns, the state will change to either "LoggedIn" or "LoginFailed".

My current plan is to add an if statement to the MapStateToProps method that check the old LoginPending status to see if that changed, and if it did, then dispatch the proper action (In reality I will execute a toast notify message).

My question is, "Is this the proper way to check for something like "logged in""? It seems awkward to do it in MapStateToProps, but since there are so many state changes happening (because of the onchange in the input elements), I can't think of a better place to do it.

```
class App extends Component {
  ....
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
          <input onChange={this.handleChange('username')}/><br/>
          <input onChange={this.handleChange('password')}/><br/><br/>
          <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Login</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it. One of the most popular way is to use `redux-thunk`. [docs](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) and [example / official recommendation](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions)

Then all the logic will reside on the action creator:

```
export const exampleAction = (username, password) => (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({type: "exampleLoading"}); // the store sets a state variable so the view can render something while this "loading" state is true
    doApiCall(username,password).then(response => {
        // here the feedback message is added on the store, so my feedback manager can render the new feedback message 
        dispatch({type: "addFeedback", payload:{message:"success!", type:"success"}});
        // here the store cleans up the "loading" variable and uses the api response if needed
        dispatch({type: "exampleLoaded", payload: response}); 
    });
}
```